# Magento 1.9 Custom model - Fatal error on Mage::getModel -> getCollection()

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am getting fatal error while retrieving data from table by custom module.
I have the following in config.xml file.

```
<config>
....
<models>
            <ebayaff>
                <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model</class>
            </ebayaff>   
            <ebayaffms>
            <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
            <ddvescore>
                <table>ddevs_core</table>
              </ddvescore>  
            </entities>
            </ebayaffms>

        </models>
...
</config>
```

> In app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Model\Ddvescore.php

```
<?php
    class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Ddvescore extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {

        public function _construct(){
             parent::_construct();
            $this->_init("ebayaffms/ddvescore");
        }

    }
```

> In app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Model\Mysql4\Ddvescore.php

```
<?php
    class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Mysql4_Ddvescore extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
    {

        public function _construct(){
            $this->_init("ebayaffms/ddvescore", "id");
        }
 }
```

> In app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Model\Mysql4\Ddvescore\Collection.php

```
<?php
    class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Mysql4_Ddvescore_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
    {

        public function _construct(){
            parent::_construct();
            $this->_init("ebayaffms/ddvescore");
        }
    }
```

While trying to retrieve the collection from table, by the following code..

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('ebayaff/ddvescore')->getCollection();
```

I am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Mysql4_Ddvescore::getCollection() in /var/www/html/....
```

Comment: Can you show full config.XML file

Comment: config.xml is there at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On config.xml,you did not define resource models properly.

**Wrong:** `model prefix` should be `ebayaffs` from `ebayaff`

**Use:** `<resourceModel>ebayaffms_mysql4</resourceModel`> for define resource model name and with it you can connect resource `model and collection model`.

```
    <ebayaffs> 
            <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>ebayaffms_mysql4</resourceModel> <!-- resource identifier define as ebayaffms_mysql4  -->
        </ebayaffs>   
        <ebayaffms_mysql4> <!-- resounce model inde
        <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
        <ddvescore>
            <table>ddevs_core</table>
          </ddvescore>  
        </entities>
        <ebayaffms_mysql4> <!-- change here -->
```

Comment: I tried with the above changes, the error has gone. But I am not retrieving the value from the table. Is there anything more to change?

Comment: remove parent::_construct(); from Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Ddvescore and Ddevs_Ebayaff_Model_Mysql4_Ddvescore_Collection

Comment: edited,please ckd....

Comment: @AmitBera i have an error when i click invoice print button, may i know the possibility of error,  Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::loadAllAttributes() in /home/abcd/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 435